# List all authors who have published books in all genres

Tags: sql, oracle

List the authorid, authorname and amountpayable for the author who has published books in all genre.

`Author` table:

```
Authorid Authorname Amountpayable
```

`Manuscript` table

```
Bookid Authorid Bookname Genre Noofcopies Amount
```

Here's the query I tried:

```
select 
    AUTHORID,
    authorname,
    amountpayable 
from author 
Where authorid IN having count(distinct "GENRE") = (select count(distinct "GENRE") from manuscript);
```

Comment: Where's **your OWN effort**?

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: Which database are you using? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic (which seems that each author's number of distinct genres is equal to the number of distinct genres) is correct. Does the following query get you the expected result?

**EDIT**: 
Changed the table name to Manuscript in the inline views.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM author a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        authorid,
        COUNT(DISTINCT Genre) num_genres
    from Manuscript
    GROUP BY authorid
) authors_genres
ON a.authorid = authors_genres.authorid
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        COUNT(DISTINCT Genre) num_genres
    FROM Manuscript
) all_genres
ON authors_genres.num_genres = all_genres.num_genres;
```

Comment: NO,i want to display all columns from author table for the one who has published books in all genre.

Comment: Yes, I understand. The above query should give you that. The `authors_genres` inline view gets the number of distinct genres for each author. The `all_genres` inline view gets the total number of distinct genres for ALL authors. If the 2 numbers are equal for an author, it indicates that the author has published in all genres. The author's details are then selected from the author table.

Comment: Ah, I just noticed that it is the Manuscript table, which contains the relationship between authors and genres. I have updated the query accordingly. Try it out!

Comment: Error in Line 7 from Keyword not found where expected.

Comment: I just added a comma that was missing after `authorid` in the `authors_genres` inline view.